# my.freeze.com netassistant

Tags: spyware

Does anyone knows how to get rid of my.freeze.com netassistant? I tried one million things, but this annoying spyware just won't go way....

Answer (score 3):

Run [HijackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) and have it fix the following entries:

```
R3 - URLSearchHook: NetAssistantBHO Class - {E38FA08E-F56A-4169-ABF5-5C71E3C153A1} - C:\Program Files\My.Freeze.com NetAssistant\NetAssistant.dll
O2 - BHO: NetAssistantBHO - {E38FA08E-F56A-4169-ABF5-5C71E3C153A1} - C:\Program Files\My.Freeze.com NetAssistant\NetAssistant.dll
```

Reboot and delete `Program Files\My.Freeze.com NetAssistant`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Reinstall and don't ever download/install horrible programs again.  And that means even the ones with the dancing monkeys and smiley faces.  No.  Stop it.  Do not do it.  I'm serious.

Comment: What about smiling monkeys?

Comment: Smash them in the face with hammers.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/), I'm pretty convinced it could uninstall me a cup of coffee in the morning if I let it. If the netassistant is not listed in the programs list, it has a window-zapper that will grab the program from one of it's windows, and uninstall from there.